# Lists inside lists don't validate with w3c?

Tags: html, validation

I've got some lists inside lists to make some fancy drop-down menus.

e.g

```
<ul>
    <li>something
        <ul>
            <li>sub menu</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is, w3c doesn't like it. Is there a way to make this validate or this is just one of these hacks that browsers can render, but w3c dislikes?

Comment: I use nested lists on my sites all the time without any complaints from the W3C Validator. Please post the relevant code or a link to your page, the problem must lie elsewhere (perhaps there's just a typo in your code somewhere).

Comment: This validates http://preview.tinyurl.com/yajz86t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is correct and valid. According to W3S nesting lists like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

is the right way (exactly as you do it). Error is somewhere else. Please provide more code.

Even with DOCTYPE XHTML 1.0 Strict W3C validates this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3
        <ul>
            <li>3.1</li>
            <li>3.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

as correct.

Answer (score 1):

this is valid using doctype xhtml 1 transitional